# I need a Query in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this output for this search, but now i need to have another output that  selecting according to all the best provider(NOME_PRESTADOR) for each service area(AREA_TRAB)
So, for example, to canalizador, the best provider is Arlindo Rui so i want to show just Arlindo Rui not Arlindo Rui and Bárbara Raquel, the some to the other areas.

[image]

Comment: Very odd GROUP BY/SELECT DISTINCT combination.

Comment: How do i do? Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Translating your table names would be helpful
Anyway, you're trying to select the best worker of each category from what I guess
Create a view using the query you posted, and then try something like this:
[mysql SELECT best of each category in a single table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9322188/mysql-select-best-of-each-category-in-a-single-table)

It's essentially the same problem